# Robust Poison regression

Tags: spss, glm, poisson, robust, rr

In glm, poisson regression, in the estimation tab there is a robust estimator option, is this the robust standard error estimator?
To use instead of modified poisson, that spss doesn't have?

A question on how to conduct robust poisson in spss

Comment: This is the type of question that would best be answered by the manual or the vendor’s help center.